# Printing a hollow circle using asterisks (so no turtle)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

For a school assignment I need to print a smiley using a hollow circle.

```
def circle(i):
    i += 1
    from math import sqrt
    result = ""
    midden = i / 2.0
    for a in range(i):
        for b in range(i):
            c = sqrt((midden - a)**2 + (midden - b)**2)
            if midden > c:
                result += "#"
            else:
                result += " "
        result += "\n"
    print(result)
circle(11)
```

The code above is what I have used to print a filled circle but i cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the circle hollow

Comment: Please try to format your code properly before posting. I've fixed it.

Comment: If you can make a filled circle, a hollow one shouldn't be much more difficult. All you need to do is only print the first and last character in each line. Do what I do when faced with a problem like this: draw it out; literally. Draw a sample 4*4 circle (or something else small), and go through it line by line while going through your code. This kind of mindset is crucial to programming.

Comment: Look there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: And there https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Python.

Comment: What are the restrictions on `i`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that will first create a matrix with spaces, and walks along 1/8th of the circle, placing '#' characters. The 7 mirroring positions can be set at the same time, filling the complete circle. Finally the matrix is converted to a string which is returned.

```
from math import sqrt

def circle(radius):
    pixels = [[' ' for x in range(2*radius+1)] for y in range(2*radius+1)]
    y = radius
    x = 0
    max = (radius + 0.5)**2
    while x <= y:
        pixels[radius+y][radius+x] = '#'
        pixels[radius+y][radius-x] = '#'
        pixels[radius-y][radius+x] = '#'
        pixels[radius-y][radius-x] = '#'
        pixels[radius+x][radius+y] = '#'
        pixels[radius+x][radius-y] = '#'
        pixels[radius-x][radius+y] = '#'
        pixels[radius-x][radius-y] = '#'
        x += 1
        if x*x + y*y >= max:
            y -= 1

    return '\n'.join([''.join([v for v in row]) for row in pixels])

print(circle(11))
```